# The universe is speeding up?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I just watched a show on spacetime. In the show they said that the universe's expansion is speeding up  instead of slowing down. They said it had to do with dark energy. I was wondering if you could explain that a bit more for me?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law

Comment: To be clear, they're talking about the *expansion* of the universe and not the "speed" of it (which doesn't exist/meaningless).

Comment: Just space, not the civil service. :-)